# Flask Restless post with many to many relationship

Tags: python, orm, flask, flask-restless

I am using flask restless and try to do a post to create a new record for many to many relationship

```
   Categories = db.Table('categories',
                          db.Column(
                              'help_request_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('help_request.id')),
                          db.Column('category_id', db.Unicode(20), db.ForeignKey('category.id')))


    class Category(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Unicode(20), primary_key=True)
        eng_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(50))
        created_by_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
        created_by = db.relationship(User)
        create_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
        imagePath = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))

        # Required for administrative interface
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.eng_name


    class HelpRequest(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        title = db.Column(db.Unicode(100))

        categories = db.relationship('Category', secondary=categories,
                                     backref=db.backref('helprequests', lazy='dynamic'))
```

How could I post a helprequest with assigned categories?? Thanks

Alex

Comment: Are you sure about your `categories` relationship on the `HelpRequest` class ? It looks like an unresolved reference ...

Comment: Yes, with Categories = db.Table...., so I don't create a class for it. https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html#many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally solved, just with correct json format and it works like magic.

{"title":"testing3","categories":  [ {"id": "a"}, {"id":"b"}]}